# mongo refer to embedded field with numeric names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My mongo documents look like below

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("59b0ee362976fb61fc54708d"),
  "id_str": "29979814",
  "eventCat": {
    "1": [2],
    "2": [10, 5, 2, 2, 10],
    "7": [10],
    "8": [10, 5]
  }
}
```

I want to check the existence of "eventCat.1" or "eventCat.2" etc. and update something. But my problem is when I refer to the fields from a function it does not work.

```
db.testCorpus.find({"id_str" : "29979814"}).forEach( function (x) { 
  tmp=x.eventCat.1; 
  if(tmp != null) {  
    print(x.eventCat.1); 
  } 
})
2017-09-20T00:08:53.115+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:98
```

If I use quotes it prints the string literal. I tried using $ with and with out quotes but to no avail.

```
db.testCorpus.find({"id_str" : "29979814"}).forEach( function (x) { 
  tmp='$x.eventCat.1'; 
  if(tmp != null) {  
    print(tmp); 
  } 
})
> $x.eventCat.1
```

I guess this is due to the numeric field name. Because, in other embedded fields I get desired outputs. Is there any way to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this :

```
db.testCorpus.find({"id_str" : "29979814"}).forEach( function (x) { 
  tmp=x.eventCat['1']; 
  if(tmp != null) {  
    print(x.eventCat['1']); 
  } 
})

> 2
```

Comment: Do embedded fields behave like associative arrays? Worked like a charm! Thank you @Julien.

Comment: In javascript object (here, your embedded field) are associative arrays. And mongodb uses javascript fort scripts. So, yes embedded fields behave like associative arrays. `foo.bar` is the same than `foo['bar']`